# Android : gradle build faild with this error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

im getting this error while building app in android studio..

**E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an error which occurs when your emulator has the `"Use host GPU"` setting turned on.

If you turn that setting off, the error will go away. Select `"Software GLES 2.0"` to disable host GPU as shown below.

[image]